# Is there an easy way of interpreting PHP code within an HAML file?

Tags: php, haml

Currently this is how I write a php file using Haml:

```
  %ul#nav
    %li
      %a
        <?php echo l('nav1'); ?>
```

Output:

```
<ul id="nav">
 <li><a><?php echo l('nav1'); ?></a></li>
```

I which I could have something like this:

```
  %ul#nav
    %li
      %a=$nav1
```

I checked pHaml and phpHaml but coudn't figure out how to use it, and I saw their last versions, and they are from 2007 (so it discouraged me even more).

Placing Php inside a Haml file is really that unpopular?
Is there a new and easy way of doing it?

Comment: Out of curiousity - what's the use case for this? I'm a little bit confused as to why you'd want to mix haml and php. Are you using haml outside of rails within a php application for the nicer formatting?

Comment: I'm not using any application, I'm just using php includes and yes I want nice formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```
  %ul#nav
    %li
      %a= $nav1
```

my reference: [Reference](http://code.google.com/p/phamlp/)

always check the right spacing

Comment: phamlp looks great. But sorry where do I have to unzip the haml and sass folders extracted from phamlp_2.2_r0094. What are the steps to make it work?